# Fetch the record for database using Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am a beginner in Codeigniter framework and I am also learning from youtube

**In my admin.php code is**

```
<?php 
class Admin extends MY_Controller {
    public function dashboard(){
        $this->load->model('articlesmodel');
        $articles = $this->articlesmodel->articles_list();
        $this->load->view('admin/dashboard', ['articles'=> $articles]);
    }
}
?>
```

**And in my dashboard.php code is**

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <th>Sr. No</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php if ( count($articles) ):?>
            <?php foreach($articles as $article): ?>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>
                        <?= $article->title ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="" class="btn btn-info">Edit</a>
                        <a href="" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
        <?php endforeach;  ?>
        <?php else:?>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">No Records Found</td>
            </tr>
        <?php endif;?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I am fetching the articles from my database in table format, but the following error is presented: **Undefined variable: articles** in dashboard.php page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change `My_Controller` to `CI_Controller` in `Admin` controller class definition.

When creating a controller class in Codeigniter, you should always extend `CI_Controller` class. Because $this->load() function is implemented in `CI_Controller` class. See the [documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/controllers.html#let-s-try-it-hello-world)

As a best practice create an array and pass it into view() function instead of initializing an array within view() function parameters. ex:

```
$data['articles'] = $this->articlesmodel->articles_list();
$this->load->view('admin/dashboard',$data);
```

Comment: My_Controller is extends from CI_Controller

Comment: @AhilKhan Then you can use only whatever which are inside in the My_Controller class. In order to use load functions from the CI_Controller, you have to create a function inside the My_Controller which returns load function from the CI_Controller. Remember this kind of inheritance isn't a right way to do

Answer (score 1):

**controller**

change these lines

```
$articles = $this->articlesmodel->articles_list();

$this->load->view('admin/dashboard', ['articles'=> $articles]);
```

to this

```
$data['articles'] = $this->articlesmodel->articles_list();

$this->load->view('admin/dashboard',$data);
```

**Tip:**
try to look at documentation syntax

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html

Comment: try this
$data['articles'] = $this->articlesmodel->articles_list();
echo "<pre>";
        print_r ($data);
        echo "</pre>";
        exit();
post the complete error also

Comment: @AhilKhan check above answer well explained